# Better approach to solve the iteration

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

```
List<emp1> empList=new ArrayList<>();
        empList.add(new emp1(1,"code1","a1"));
        empList.add(new emp1(2,"code2","a2"));
Set<emp1> empSet=new HashSet<>();
        empSet.add(new emp1(1,"code3","a3"));

for(emp1 e:empList) {
            for(emp1 a:empSet) {
                if(e.getB().equals(a.getB())||e.getA()==a.getA()||e.getC().equals(a.getC())) {
                    System.out.println("equals");
                }
            }
        }

class emp1{
    int a;
    String b;
    String c;
```

How to achieve this using lambda or any other better approach?
It should compare each elements in list to set and tell if its present? 
need to compare each elements a,b,c , if present it should return equals

Answer (score 0):

Even though he forEach doesn't really make much sense, but you could possibly attain it as :

```
    empList.stream()
            .filter(empSet::contains)
            .map(a -> "equals")
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: need to compare each elements a,b,c , if present it should return equals.Contains will check for all the same object if hashcode is overridden.But need to check individual element in the object.